# How to get values inside nested keys in Firebase on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get values inside two nested keys in Firebase.

[image: This is my database structure]:

I need to put all the value of name inside an array. Here is my code where I'm accessing just the node "user". I was thinking that I could use "queryOrderedByKey" one after another, but in that case xCode crashes and says something like multiple quires aren't allowed.

```
        Database.database().reference().child("user").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        if snapshot.value != nil {

            let result = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            if let name = result["name"] as? String {
                self.myArray.append(name)
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        }
    }
```

And this is what I'm getting when printing the result.
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer

```
        Database.database().reference().child("user").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        if let dictinoary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            if let myFinalStep = dictinoary["GeneralInformation"] as? [String: Any] {
                print(myFinalStep["name"])

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code will iterate over every user in the /users node and leave an observer on the /user node so if any users are added, this code will send an event to the app. It's not clear if that was the desired result as the original question seems to lean toward doing it as needed; if so, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tigran's answer is very good but here's an alternative. This code iterates over each child node within 'user' node and looks into a deep path to get the name. Note this leaves a childAdded observer to the user node so if any additional nodes are added, this will fire again.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("user")
usersRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
    if let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "GeneralInformation")
                          .childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String {
        print(name)
    }
})
```

If you want to read the names in once and not leave an observer, here's an alternative

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("user")
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        if let name = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "GeneralInformation")
                          .childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String {
            print(name)
        }
    }
})
```

I was feeling Swifty so here's a third variant if you don't want to leave an observer. Note that if the node containing the name does not exist, the resulting array will contain "No Name" at that index.

```
let usersRef = self.ref.child("uses")
usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    let myUsers = snapshot.children.allObjects.map { $0 as! DataSnapshot }
    let names = myUsers.map { $0.childSnapshot(forPath: "GeneralInformation")
                                .childSnapshot(forPath: "name")
                                .value as? String ?? "No Name" }
    print(names)
})
```