# Getting nested children from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to populate a table view with values from my Firebase database. I was able to use queryOrdered on the root of my database to get the children I required, as seen here:

```
func oneTimeInit() {
        databaseRef?.queryOrdered(byChild: "Seasons").observe(.value, with:
            { snapshot in
                for item in snapshot.children {
                    self.seasons.append(Season( snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot))
                }
                self.seasonsTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

But now I am trying to get the children of the next node in my database. I tried to do this by calling queryOrdered on the child of the root but I'm not getting any data. Here is my code:

```
func oneTimeInit() {
        databaseRef?.child("Seasons").queryOrdered(byChild: season.name).observe(.value, with:
            { snapshot in
                for item in snapshot.children {
                    print("ITEM VALUE: \(item)")
                    self.races.append(Race(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot))
                }
                self.racesTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

The Database contains, at its highest level, Cross Country Seasons, which each contain Cross Country Races, which each contain results. Im able to populate the Seasons table but not the Races table, and so on.

Heres the Json structure of my database:

```
{
  "Seasons" : {
    "XC 2018" : {
      "NCAA DI West Regional" : {
        "Men" : {
          "Results" : {
            "Aaron BRUMBAUGH" : {
              "finishTime" : "31:59.0",
              "lapTimes" : [ "5:05.1", "10:43.3", "11:07.1", "5:03.5" ],
              "name" : "Aaron BRUMBAUGH",
              "position" : "118",
              "splitTimes" : [ "5:05.1", "15:48.4", "26:55.5", "31:59.0" ],
              "team" : "Santa Clara",
              "year" : "SR"
            },
            "Addison DEHAVEN" : {
              "finishTime" : "29:47.8",
              "lapTimes" : [ "4:58.2", "10:14.0", "10:04.1", "4:31.5" ],
              "name" : "Addison DEHAVEN",
              "position" : "7",
              "splitTimes" : [ "4:58.2", "15:12.2", "25:16.3", "29:47.8" ],
              "team" : "Boise State",
              "year" : "SR"
            },
            "Ahmed MUHUMED" : {
              "finishTime" : "30:08.1",
              "lapTimes" : [ "4:58.6", "10:14.6", "10:08.5", "4:46.4" ],
              "name" : "Ahmed MUHUMED",
              "position" : "29",
              "splitTimes" : [ "4:58.6", "15:13.2", "25:21.7", "30:08.1" ],
              "team" : "Boise State",
              "year" : "SO"
            },
```

As of now there is only one "Season" (XC 2018) with one "Race" (NCAA D1 West Regional). I'm trying to get a reference to all of the "Races" under the "Season" XC 2018.

The variable season.name would contain the value "XC 2018". With my second one time init I am trying to look at the children of "XC 2018".

Comment: You tagged your question with `google-cloud-firestore`, but your code and data seem to be for the Firebase Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and their APIs and data model are very different. Please use the correct tag `firebase-realtime-database` going forward.

Comment: Your structure is pretty deep so you may want to consider denormalizing your data. In your initial query, you're receiving in the snapshot the children of the */Seasons* node. The first child node is */Seasons/XC 2018* which is well and good but then that node has a child *.../NSAA DI West Regional* which then has a child node *.../Men* and then a child node *.../Results*. That's going to extraordinary hard to navigate in code. Then you appear to be trying to read some data from the child nodes with the *for...loop* but your not defining which child nodes... you can't just use 'item'.

Comment: Please see this well aged, classical hand tooled post [Denormalizing is Normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) to get a better idea of flattening your structure to make the data 'easier' to get to. Then take a look at [Read and Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) for some tips on that topic. Then see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567407/how-to-get-values-inside-nested-keys-in-firebase-on-swift/51580622#51580622) for some tips on reading firebase nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Been a minute since I'm dealing with final projects in other classes as well, I read the article on denormalizing data and while I agree it seems like a much better way to structure the database, I don't have the time to make the cascade of changes it would require in my app. I was able to fix the issue however!