# How to read nested data from realtime database firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database is structured like this:

```
{
  "username123" : {
    "6642" : {
      "latitude" : 37.861639,
      "longitude" : -4.785556,
      "name" : "CEPSA"
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that every user will have a list of favorite gas stations, identified by their ID (6642 in the example). However, I can't figure out how to get the data. Any help please?
Edit: I tried this but it obviously doesn't work since I get back the whole thing, I just can't figure out how to get the id, latitude, longitude and name.

```
ref.child(user).getData(completion:  { error, snapshot in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return;
        }
        if let gasStationDict = snapshot.value as? [String:String] {
            guard let id = snapshot.value, let name = gasStationDict["name"], let longitude = gasStationDict["longitude"], let latitude = gasStationDict["latitude"] else { return }
            let gasStation = GasStation(name: name, longitude: longitude, latitude: latitude, favorita: true, id: id)
         }
    });
```

ref is initialized like this:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference()
```

and user is:

```
guard var user = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "User") else { return }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not a code-writing service but are happy to help with existing code you've attempted. Also, it's important to know what your goal is; 'get the data' is too broad. Please update the question with the code you've attempted and clarify what you're trying do.

Comment: @Jay I added the bit of code that I tried, I know it could never work but I can't figure out what could. I am trying to get both the id and the nested data inside, but since the ID is unknown to me I can't do ref.child("\(user)/\(id)")

Comment: Can you edit the question to show how your `ref` and `user` variables are initialized?

Comment: Oh - your structure does not match your code; e.g. code is showing `snapshot.value` as `[String: String]` and it's actually `[String: [String: String]]` or `[String: [String: Int]`. I would personally abandon that practice and use `childSnapshot` to access nested data - it's a lot easier to read. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315050/not-able-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database/68320540#68320540) and maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567407/how-to-get-values-inside-nested-keys-in-firebase-on-swift/51580622#51580622)

Comment: Two additional thoughts: When a user authenticates to Firebase, they have a `uid` which is a unique identifier tied to that user. That's a really good tool to use to store data in Firebase for that user. e.g. intead of `username123`, a better option is to have the node key be the users uid. Secondly - storing User in UserDefaults is not generally recommended. That space is really for well, user defaults - app font size, background color, that kind of thing.

Comment: Great examples in your comments Jay. Do you feel like writing them up in a small answer? What way we can get closure here and others (including me) are more likely to find it going forward.

Comment: I added an answer that should point you in the right direction - please ask any questions about it if something is unclear. @FrankvanPuffelen done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is the Firebase structure presented in the question doesn't match the code:

```
user_id
   gas_station_id
      name
```

and the code is attempting to read it like this

```
if let gasStationDict = snapshot.value as? [String:String]
```

Where the structure is more like this `[String:  [String: String]]` or possibly `[String: [String: Int]]`

I suggest another solution using `.childSnapshot` to get deeply nested data. It's easier to read and way easier to maintain

I would also suggest changing the structure. In NoSQL databases it's often best practice to disassociate node keys from the data they contain.

For example, in your structure, 6642 is station ID. What if, in the future the station ID changes? You would literally have to go through your entire database, search for that, delete those nodes and whatever they contain and then re-write them. ugh!

Here's a better structure

```
{
  "username123" : {
    a_firebase_generated_node_key : { //using .childByAutoId to create
      "latitude" : 37.861639,
      "longitude" : -4.785556,
      "name" : "CEPSA"
      "station_id: "6652"
    }
  }
}
```

now you can change any aspect of the station and won't have to change any references to it.

Then the code to read and print all of the stations using `childSnapshot`

```
func printUsersGasStations() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("gas_stations").child("username123")
    ref.getData(completion: { error, snapshot in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        //this next line takes all of the stations and creates
        //   an ordered array of them as DataSnapshots
        let allStationsSnap = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]

        for stationSnap in allStationsSnap {
            let stationId = stationSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "station_id").value as? String ?? "No Station ID"
            let lat = stationSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "lat").value as? Double ?? 0.0
            let lon = stationSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "lon").value as? Double ?? 0.0
            let name = stationSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
            print(stationId, lat, lon, name)
        }
    })
}
```