# while fetching data from firebase found this error Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'

Tags: swift, firebase

this is a code which I do for fetching data from firebase, its runs okay but after some days I can face this type of error, can any one solve it

Source code:

```
let refer = Database.database().reference()
        _ = UserDefaults.standard
        refer.child("Users").observe(. value) { (snapshot) in
            //get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
            var dataModel = UserData()
            for i in value.values{
                dataModel = UserData(imageUrl: [i["ImageUrl"\][1] as? String,
                                     uploading_date: i["Uploading_date"] as? String,
                                     uploading_time: i["Uploading_time"] as? String,
                                     description_data: i["Discription"] as? String)
                data_list.append  (dataModel)
            }
            debugPrint(data_list)
            print("printing length of data :::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
            debugPrint(data_list.count)
            onSuccess(data_list)
```

How can i get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: The value is `AnyObject`(unspecified), the compiler **must** know the real type.

Comment: how can I change it? because 2 of them have String data type and 2 of them are int or may be date

Comment: I'm in the same situation as the compiler. I have no idea. If you want to subscript by key you have to downcast the type to a dictionary and by index to an array.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is `i` that you need to explain to the compiler what it is as a first step.

Comment: The issue is how the objects are being referenced; it's too ambiguous. It's often (much) simpler to leave Firebase data, like a DataShot, as a firebase object instead of trying to cast it to a deeply nested Dictionary. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315050/not-able-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database/68320540#68320540) for how that's done using `childSnapshot`. Maybe check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51567407/how-to-get-values-inside-nested-keys-in-firebase-on-swift/51580622#51580622) as well.

Comment: As another thought, I like object initializers so you may want to consider passing the snapshot to the object and letting it pull the data out of it - makes for simpler code `let dataModel = UserData(fromSnapshot: childSnap)` and then the object can get childSnapshot data from the datasnapshot and populate it's properties.